# how to check a file is existing or not in VB based on filename that pick from date

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro that can check and open file based on filename. 
ex:

1. 15.xlsm As opened workbook
2. 12.xlsm As a target
3. 16.xlsm As the future workbook

So while I click a button in 15.xlsm that will open the previous file (12.xlsm). But in future, when the 16.xlsm is created, the 16.xlsm must open the previous workbook (15.xlsm).

I was trying with this code

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim a, x As Integer
    Dim path, filename As String
    Dim varday, varyest As Long

    varday = Day(Range("A1"))

    For x = 1 To 30
        varyest = varday - x
        filename = "" & varyest & ".xlsm"
        path = "F:\Kemal\" & filename & ""

        If Dir(path) = "" Then 

        Else
            Workbooks.Open filename:=path
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

but that code has open all workbook like 12.xlsm, 10.xlsm, 9.xlsm, and create unlimited messagebox. Yeah I know the algorithm but, how to put it into code is the big problem. anyone help me, pls.

So, How to check previous file is exist or not with date that placed on every workbook name?

Comment: Put `exit sub` after `workbooks.open`?

Answer (score -1):

to know if file exists :

```
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FileExists(p)
```

If you want to check MANY files, you may want to use the content of the whole folder and lookup the array.

if target workbooks has a Workbook_Open that's not to be launched:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
workbooks.open(file)
Application.EnableEvents = true
```

Question is a bit fuzzy to me, I hope this answers